# Fastapi class AuthenticationBackend: raise AttributeError(item) AttributeError: transport

Tags: python, fastapiusers

I use authorization and authentication with fastapi-users. And when working with the AuthenticationBackend class, I use JWT as a transport attribute. I tried to rewrite and update the library, but it didn't help, the attribute error was popping up all the time

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 61, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 68, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 467, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Pyton\MyProject\fastapi_shop\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    fastapi_users.get_auth_router(UserRead, UserCreate),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fastapi_users\fastapi_users.py", line 84, in get_auth_router
    return get_auth_router(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fastapi_users\router\auth.py", line 43, in get_auth_router
    **backend.transport.get_openapi_login_responses_success(),
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_model_construction.py", line 210, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: transport
```

I took the code from their documentation
https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/10.1/configuration/full-example/

```
auth_backend = AuthenticationBackend(
    name="jwt",
    transport=bearer_transport,
    get_strategy=get_jwt_strategy,
)
```

imports:

```
from fastapi_users.authentication import (
    AuthenticationBackend,
    BearerTransport,
    JWTStrategy,
)
```

reinstalled the library, rewrote the code again. looked in the very code of the library file, the class itself has such an attribute

Comment: Your code is incomplete and it's hard to help you this way. Have you defined `bearer_transport` and `get_jwt_strategy`? How?

Comment: the code was taken entirely from the documentation